# How to get rid of g++ hash_map deprecation warning?

Tags: c++, g++, hashmap, deprecated

When I compile a c++ application I'm writing that makes use of hash_map, I get this warning on g++ 4.3.2:

You are using the deprecated header . To eliminate this warning, use an ANSI-standard header file or use hte -Wno-deprecated compiler flag.

```
9> #include <ext/hash_map>
```

What include replaces this?  I've searched for a while on google, and can't find anything except for people having similar problems, but no solution.

Comment: Why was this guy's question edited to match the answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My very first Google hit for "[g++ hash_map deprecated](http://www.google.com/search?q=g%2B%2B+hash_map+deprecated)" takes me to [a page](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ember/+spec/ember-deprecated-cleanup) that includes a list of things to use instead of the deprecated headers and classes.

For `hash_map`, the list suggests using [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), in the `unordered_map` header. The class is new for [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1).

Comment: For some reason I get different results on Google, but this is a perfect response.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess I've just trained Google better about what sorts of results I want to see. Happy coding.

Comment: My very first hit on Google for that query is this question on SO...  Damn you, Heisenberg! (shaking my fist in the air menacingly)

Comment: Also note that this is a C++11 feature so you might need to enable this in your compiler.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that that new data structure is called `unordered_map`

```
<tr1/unordered_map>
```

found in the `std::tr1` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

When including , do not forget to add the following compiler option; "-std=c++0x", otherwise the compiler will report an error