# How do I compile Contraction Hierarchies by KIT?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, compiler-warnings

I am trying to compile the [Contraction Hierarchies Implementation](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/english/routeplanning.php) by KIT.

This software has been published in 2009 and obviously not been maintained since then. Since a few things have changed in the mean time (with new C++ standards and compiler versions) the code does not compile off the shelf anymore.

README is not very verbose when it comes to instructions on compiling and says you should only invoke `make`. However, using make gives me the following error:

```
g++  -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter  -O6   -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/hash_map:60:0,
                 from command/../io/../datastr/graph/../../io/serialize.h:26,
                 from command/../io/../datastr/graph/edge.h:26,
                 from command/../io/../datastr/graph/graph.h:59,
                 from command/../io/createGraph.h:28,
                 from command/NodeOrder.h:29,
                 from main.cpp:35:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
 #warning \
  ^
command/../processing/../EliminationWeight.h:42:35: error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static const Type MAX_VALUE = __DBL_MAX__;
                                   ^
command/../processing/../EliminationWeight.h:43:36: error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static const Type MIN_VALUE = -__DBL_MAX__;
                                    ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

What do I have to do to make this compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the software compile without errors, a few steps are necessary. I have tested these instruction with gcc 4.8.1 and Boost 1.53.0.

### a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression

(I have already answered this subproblem in detail [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17586165/447490) but will repeat the important steps here.)

The first compilation error we encounter is due to the software using non-standard extensions of the GCC compiler. It seems that at the time of the software's development these did not have to be enabled by a compiler switch but modern GCC requires this. However, for future compatibility, we will just get rid of them and implement the features in a standard compliant way.

The compiler tells us that the problem is in lines 42 and 43 of `EliminationWeight.h`. These are the lines in that file:

```
static const Type MAX_VALUE = __DBL_MAX__;
static const Type MIN_VALUE = -__DBL_MAX__;
```

GCC complains here because initialization of doubles in a class body is not covered by the standard. Instead, we should do it separately. So remove the initialization and change the lines to the following:

```
static const Type MAX_VALUE;
static const Type MIN_VALUE;
```

Also remove the `#include <limits>` as we no longer need that in this file.

Since we still want to initialize these values, we take a look at `main.cpp` and find line 84 and following:

```
// doesn't look nice, but required by the compiler (gcc 4)
const EdgeWeight Weight::MAX_VALUE;
const EliminationWeight::Type EliminationWeight::MAX_VALUE;
const EliminationWeight::Type EliminationWeight::MIN_VALUE;
```

This looks like the perfect place to do our initializations. Change lines 86 and 87 to contain the following code:

```
const EliminationWeight::Type EliminationWeight::MAX_VALUE = std::numeric_limits< EliminationWeight::Type >::max();
const EliminationWeight::Type EliminationWeight::MIN_VALUE = -std::numeric_limits< EliminationWeight::Type >::max();
```

Also add

```
#include <limits>
```

to `main.cpp` because we are now using the `std::numeric_limits` class from that header.

### collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Compilation will now work but linking will fail with a huge error message. (I have already covered this problem [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17645265/447490) but will repeat the gist of it here.)

All the errors will be about linking of Boost::Regex. This is the complete error message on my machine:

```
g++ -lboost_regex -lboost_iostreams -o main main.o 
main.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::unwind_extra_block(bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE18unwind_extra_blockEb[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE18unwind_extra_blockEb]+0x2c): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
main.o: In function `void boost::re_detail::raise_error > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE]+0x7d): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE]+0xb1): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[_ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE]+0xcb): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
main.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator boost::re_detail::re_is_set_member, char, boost::regex_traits >, unsigned int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, boost::re_detail::re_set_long const*, boost::re_detail::regex_data > > const&, bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail16re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb[_ZN5boost9re_detail16re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb]+0x17b): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail16re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb[_ZN5boost9re_detail16re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb]+0x4c0): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform(char const*, char const*) const'
main.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::extend_stack()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12extend_stackEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12extend_stackEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
main.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_imp()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv]+0xc): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv]+0x19e): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv]+0x254): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE9match_impEv]+0x3c6): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
main.o: In function `bool boost::regex_match, std::allocator, std::allocator > >, char, boost::regex_traits > >(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, boost::match_results, std::allocator >::const_iterator, std::allocator > > >&, boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11regex_matchISt11char_traitsIcESaIcESaINS_9sub_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEEEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbRKSbIT2_T_T0_ERNS_13match_resultsINSJ_14const_iteratorET1_EERKNS_11basic_regexISG_T3_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE[_ZN5boost11regex_matchISt11char_traitsIcESaIcESaINS_9sub_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEEEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbRKSbIT2_T_T0_ERNS_13match_resultsINSJ_14const_iteratorET1_EERKNS_11basic_regexISG_T3_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE]+0xe9): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
main.o: In function `void Command::createVector(std::string const&, std::vector >&, double)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_[_ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_]+0x4a): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_[_ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_]+0x7b): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_[_ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_]+0xac): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.o: In function `void Command::createVector(std::string const&, std::vector >&, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Command12createVectorIjEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_[_ZN7Command12createVectorIjEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_]+0x48): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Command12createVectorIjEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_[_ZN7Command12createVectorIjEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_]+0x79): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Command12createVectorIjEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_[_ZN7Command12createVectorIjEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_]+0xaa): more undefined references to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)' follow
main.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_match()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE11match_matchEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE11match_matchEv]+0x371): undefined reference to `boost::match_results, std::allocator > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results, std::allocator > > > const&)'
main.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_dot_repeat_slow()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE21match_dot_repeat_slowEv[_ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE21match_dot_repeat_slowEv]+0x229): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

It seems like Boost::Regex is not found at all. Note that this is one of the Boost libraries that need to be compiled and linked into your application to work. The following is under the assumption that you have obtained a compiled version and it is in your system's library directory.

When linking, the order in which libraries and object files are passed to GCC via command line parameters is important. For some reason what seems to have worked with GCC in 2009 is no longer working now. This can be fixed by changing the order in which `make` is passing the parameters to GCC.

Locate `Makefile` in the project root directory and find line 6:

```
$(CXX) $(LINK) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Here you can see that `make` is passing the linker switches containing the Boost libraries before the object file. (If you can't, don't worry. It is not necessary that you understand Makefiles to follow this explanation.) To make this work with current GCC we will change the order of the parameters. Line 6 of your `Makefile` should look like this:

```
$(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) $(LINK)
```

Save it and run `make` again. Compilation and linking should now proceed without errors.

### warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header

You will still see a compiler warning telling you that you are using deprecated header files. You can ignore this warning. However, it might be possible that newer versions of GCC don't come with this header file and compilation will fail.

If you want to fix it, here is how.

The problem lies in `io/serialize.h` which includes `<ext/hash_map>`. The C++11 standard [replaces this with `unordered_map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722413/447490). So we fix the code to use that. Line 128 will be

```
typedef __gnu_cxx::hash_map<key_type, data_type> HashMap;
```

Change this to use `unordered_map` as follows:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<key_type, data_type> HashMap;
```

Now we also need to fix the header. Remove the include of `<ext/hash_map>` and replace line 26 with

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
```

The `<algorithm>` include is needed because obviously `<ext/hash_map>` also provided `std::sort` and `std::reverse` for the `hash_map`. These functions are now in the `<algorithm>` header and the code relies on the fact that these are included by this file.

Since this is a C++11 feature we need to tell GCC that we want support for that. Go to `compiler.make` in the project's root directory and find line 6 which should be

```
CXXFLAGS = $(DEBUG) $(WARNING) $(OPTIMIZER)
```

At the end of the line add the switch to use C++11:

```
CXXFLAGS = $(DEBUG) $(WARNING) $(OPTIMIZER) -std=c++11
```

Run `make clean` and `make` again and your code should compile without any errors or warnings.